# Getting word count from a python list

Tags: python

I have a trouble counting words in a list.

```
My_list = ["white is a colour", "orange is a fruit", "blue is a mood", "I like candy"]
```

What I need the script to output is the number of words in the list (15 in this case).

```
len(My_list)
```

will return "4" (the number of items).

```
for item in My_list:
    print len(item.split())
```

will give me length of each item.

Is there a way to get the word count from a list?
Ideally, I would also like to append each word into a new list (each word is an item).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a list of all the individual words with:

```
words = [word for line in My_list for word in line.split()]
```

To *just* count the words, use `sum()`:

```
sum(len(line.split()) for line in My_list)
```

Demo:

```
>>> My_list = ["white is a colour", "orange is a fruit", "blue is a mood", "I like candy"]
>>> [word for line in My_list for word in line.split()]
['white', 'is', 'a', 'colour', 'orange', 'is', 'a', 'fruit', 'blue', 'is', 'a', 'mood', 'I', 'like', 'candy']
>>> sum(len(line.split()) for line in My_list)
15
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the sum of the words in every item:

```
sum (len(item.split()) for item in My_list)
```

To put all the words into one list:

```
sum ([x.split() for x in My_list], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is a very good idea. Another way would be to use join and split:

```
l = " ".join(My_list).split()
```

Now 'l' is a list with all the word tokens as items and you can simply use len() on it:

```
len(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always go for the simple loop.

```
My_list = ["white is a colour", "orange is a fruit", "blue is a mood", "I like candy"]

c = 0
for item in My_list:
    for word in item.split():
        c += 1

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
My_list = ["white is a colour", "orange is a fruit", "blue is a mood", "I like candy"]

word_count = 0
for phrase in My_list:
    # increment the word_count variable by the number of words in the phrase.
    word_count += len(phrase.split())

print word_count
```